# on event don't trigger after replaceWith()

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i click on a `<span>`, the span changes to an input field

```
$('table td').on('click', 'span', function() {
    var $el = $(this);

    var $input = $('<input/>').val($el.text()).attr('class', 'form-control');
    $el.replaceWith($input);

    var save = function() {
        var $p = $ ('<span>').text( $input.val() );
        $input.replaceWith($p);
    };

    $input.one('blur', save).focus();
});

$('input').on('change', function() {
    var target = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'url',
        data: {
            value: target.val(),
            ruleId: target.data('rule'),
            date: target.data('date')
        },
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('updated');
        }
    });
});
```

After it, i need to catch when the input changes

But it does not trigger the `$('input').on('change', function() {` function anymore...

Comment: Most of the time(if not always) if jQuery removes an element from DOM, it also destroys all the listeners attached to it.

Comment: @George yes everything is wrapped in ```$(document).ready(function()```

Comment: _The .on() method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set of elements in the jQuery object_ and your input isn't on the DOM when `$('input').on('change', function() {` is executed

Comment: From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/#entry-longdesc) in the **Additional Infos** : *"The .replaceWith() method removes all data and event handlers associated with the removed nodes."* You could always use the native (and relatively new) DOM API's [`replaceWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/replaceWith): `$el[0].replaceWith($other[0])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try to use this instead

```
$(document).on('change','input',function(){
 // your code here
}
```

Hope the helps

Answer (score 1):

***bind event to document and not to element will solve your problem.***

```
$(document).on('change', '.item', function(event) {
```

refer [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: we can add unique class to element and bind to that one will minimize the bind scope.

Comment: @Yooouuri, if it worked, than accepting as answer will be helpful to other who will be landing here for same problem.